# Applying MSI command line parameters to administrative install

Tags: windows-installer

Our installer (Windows Installer) accepts a command line parameter in the form PROPERTY=value. The parameter will put down one of 3 files depending on its value (or its absence). This works well when installing using...

```
msiexec.exe /i filename.msi PROPERTY=value
```

I'd like to perform an administrative install and pass the PROPERTY=value parameter so that the extracted image mirrors the normal installation when that parameter is used. I've tried the following...

```
msiexec.exe /a filename.msi PROPERTY=value /qn TARGETDIR=C:\MSIImagePath

msiexec.exe /a filename.msi /qn TARGETDIR=C:\MSIImagePath PROPERTY=value

msiexec.exe /a "filename.msi PROPERTY=value" /qn TARGETDIR=C:\MSIImagePath
```

The third command there flat out does not work and the first two produce an image as if the installer were run without specifying the PROPERTY=value parameter, in other words as if I installed like...

```
msiexec.exe /i filename.msi
```

How can I perform an administrative install passing in the PROPERTY=value parameter our MSI expects and have the extracted image mirror the files that should be installed when using that property/value combination?

EDIT: Here is the root problem behind the question.

We are moving our build process to Azure VMs and using Bamboo to control it. We use InstallShield to produce installers. When we build patches it is my understanding that InstallShield must have access to the baseline installer image to know how to create the update MSP. I was also told that I can create the baseline installer image using administrative install which seems to be exactly what I need. I am not the installer expert on the team, but so far this all makes sense to me.

When we build the initial MSI we call IsCmdBld.exe twice, each time passing a different release name using the -r parameter. The first pass produces a single MSI that is distributed to users. The second pass creates an uncompressed folder that looks exactly as you see when performing an administrative install. It contains a smaller MSI and all of the files in the installation are extracted to the folder. It is this folder that InstallShield uses as the baseline installer image from which to produce patch logic.

One of the files we install can have 4 different file contents dictated by the PROPERTY=value parameter. This file applies certain restrictions on the product and is intended to be used by administrators to limit some features for added security. To pull this off the InstallShield project has 4 components and each of those uses the same filename for the installed file and different filenames for the source file. I'll call the installed file the Security Control File and the 4 source files the Security Restrictions Files. The Security Restrictions Files are not installed directly, one of them is installed as the Security Control File based on the PROPERTY=value option (or its absence.)

Hopefully everything thus far makes sense. Since we have this somewhat odd setup where the Security Control File is dynamic and changes during the installation InstallShield must pick one of the 4 Security Restriction Files to use as the source for the Security Control File when building the MSI. The uncompressed installer image that is produced when calling IsCmdBld.exe uses a Security Restriction File that is *different* than the one that is chosen when performing an administrative install. For this reason when building patches I cannot accurately recreate the baseline installer image required to produce the patch. This was not a problem before when we had a static build machine and the start state of a build was the end state of the prior build. We always had the initial installer baseline image in place as it was created by IsCmdBld.exe.

I can work around it just fine by performing the administrative install and copying the required Security Control File into the baseline image or by simply zipping the required baseline image and using that. I was just hoping I could pass PROPERTY=value to administrative install to recreate the baseline perfectly in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. An administrative install isn't really an install in the same sense as an actual install. The files are laid out according to the static values in the MSI file. One of the main uses for administrative installs is with patching, where you can patch an administrative install, or use two administrative install images to generate a patch. If the file locations were not as defined in the MSI then patch generation would fail because it wouldn't know where the files are.

It might be useful if you explained the problem you're trying to solve and why that location is required to be as if it were an actual install (which it isn't). What are you doing with the admin image that requires that layout?

Comment: Thanks, PhilDW. That makes sense and your reason #2 is what we're doing. We are using our first installer administrative install as the baseline from which to produce patches. I've added additional info to my question as to why this is not working for us. We have a somewhat nontraditional file that is throwing the administrative install footprint off from what it must be.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, PhilDW. I think you are correct in that it cannot be done. I've changed direction a little bit and have just zipped the first uncompressed install folder and made it accessible to subsequent builds for creating a patch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the property setting to be respected during the later installs phase (rather than just during the administrative install), you may need to modify the resulting .msi file's Property table. Or create a transform to set the property and apply that at installation time:

```
msiexec.exe /i admin.msi TRANSFORMS=sets_a_property.mst /qn
```

This is similar to advertisement where, depending on the intended use of the property, you may need to ensure it's applied during the on-demand installation rather than just the advertisement. In that scenario you'd apply the transform during advertisement with `/t`:

```
msiexec /j filename.msi /t sets_a_property.mst /qn
```

Note that in your original example, `targetdir=...` is suspect, as the property is most likely `TARGETDIR`. Properties with lower-case letters are considered private, and attempts to set them externally may not be respected.

Comment: Thank you for the targetdir correction, it does work in lower, but I did see the character case notes you describe in the doc.

Comment: You say "rather than during the administrative install..."  The admin install is where I'd like the property applied. I can't seem to get the property applied when using msiexec /a. If possible I'd like to do this so that the files extracted to TARGETDIR when using /a mirror what is seen in the installation path during a normal installation. At no point am I going to be installing this application from the admin install. I'm using it to recreate the base installer image from which to build subsequent patches in our build process and to do so I need to use the the PROPERTY=value param.

Comment: Ah, but admin installs use source folder paths instead of target folder paths. (See DefaultDir of the Directory table.) I don't think that changing this will be beneficial.